# Cant upload template to Openshift Origin

Tags: openshift-origin

When I'm trying to upload template with command:

```
oc create -f postgres.json
```

CLI returns

```
error: bufio.Scanner: token too long
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a known issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12582.

You can work around it by making sure no line in your YAML file is longer than 64k characters.